# How to stop variables from showing output

Tags: variables, smarty

I can't seem to find a way to stop the smarty variables from showing their output, i.e if i write `{$foo}` or `{$foo++}` it will show whatever the value of `$foo` is in the output.

Can anyone tell me how I can stop them from showing the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a core feature of Smarty to output the values of variables.

If you don't want or like what's being displayed, you can

- stop assigning variables to your smarty object from within PHP
- comment the variable out like with `{* $foo *}`

Comment: What about hiding output "1" of {$foo|@shuffle} if {$foo = $foo|@shuffle} is not working?

Answer (score 6):

I used this.

```
{$i++|truncate:0:""}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the long form, instead of `{$foo++}` you would use `{$foo = $foo + 1}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
{capture}{$foo|@some_operation_on_foo}{/capture}
```